# Xamarin Android publish breaks app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

My android app builds and runs just fine on debug, but when I switch it to publish and deploy the app manually, things start breaking. Images are missing, entry fields don't work (placeholder text shows up, and the keyboard pops when I click on the field, but nothing I type in shows up), and some of my tap handlers aren't working.  Are there any suggestions on what would possibly cause this?  Seems odd that just changing to publish would cause that...

Comment: Try to change your `Release` linker settings to `Don't Link/None` and see if the same behavior of the `Debug` deploy comes back. If so, you have a problem with the linker stripping things it shouldn't. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/

Comment: Looks like that what it was... I changed the linker to don't link and it runs, but the apk file is huge now.  I'll have to figure out what the linker was missing.  Thanks for the link, should help a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your `Release` linker settings to `Don't Link/None` and see if the same behavior of the `Debug` deploy comes back. If so, you have a problem with the linker stripping things it shouldn't.

developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking

This will of course increase the size of the package dramatically and you'll want to play around with the different preservation methods.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/#Preserving_Code

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/#falseflag

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/#linkskip

I would highly recommend attempting to `linkskip` any third party assemblies in full before going into complete investigation mode. You can then use a `Custom Linker` configuration file to define exactly what you should not eliminate via the linker:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/custom_linking/